# How to find unique count of clients who have TimeFollowUp = "6 Months" and TimeFollowUp Not Equal to "6 Months"?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

How to find unique count of clients who have TimeFollowUp = "6 Months" and  TimeFollowUp Not Equal to "6 Months" in MS Excel?

[image]

Comment: Try the `countif`function.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2010 and earlier: Pivot the pivot

Build a pivot table from the data, Pull TimeFollowUp into the rows area, pull clients underneath TimeFollowUp in the rows area. Build a pivot table based on that table and count the clients.

For Excel 2013 and later, add the data to the data model, and a pivot table can use the "Distinct Count" option in the values area.

See a more comprehensive step by step of these methods over at Debra Dahlgliesh's [Contextures](http://www.contextures.com/pivottablecountunique.html) site.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Cant we do it with any formula??

Comment: Not really, no. If this were possible with a formula in a cell, then people would not jump through all these hoops. You may want to roll your own VBA function for this, though.